# Why are my EU Law questions being downvoted?

Tags: discussion

Some down-voter is un-ceremonious and in-sensitive to my time and learning, with no comment, my questions from Robert Schütze's [*European Union Law* 2 ed. 2018](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/eu-law-9780198714927?cc=ca&lang=en&). I have to learn EU Law myself and use my library's books, and I spend time and effort posting these questions and assisting EU questions that I can answer.

Can whoever the down-voter please stop? At least suggest what I can improve? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The problems associated with questions arising from novice readings of law books has been addressed extensively.  See answers to the following questions:

- [Are questions about law books on-topic?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/592/10)
- [Why are questions from law books off-topic?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/857/10)
- [Why were these 4 questions based on 2 jurisprudents closed?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/456/10)